# Using the '->' operator in R to define a function requires parentheses to work

Tags: r, syntax

I was playing with R and its assignment operators a little and I found out that if I want to use the `->` operator to write a function into a variable, I need to enclose the definition inside parentheses like so:

```
(function(x) {
return(x)
}) -> my_func

my_func("hi")
```

The following doesn't work as expected:

```
function(x) {
    return(x)
} -> my_func

my_func("hi")
```

The output seems also rather strange to me:

```
function (x)  my_func <- {
    return(x) }

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "my_func" Traceback:
```

Does anyone know why that is? My guess is that it will have something to do with the precedence and associativity of operators, but I can't put my finger on it...

Comment: And the reason for wanting to assign a function like this is...?

Comment: @useR purely academic :)

Comment: As seen from the output, in the second case, everything after `function(x)` is considered as the function's body. And the body is the assignment of the return value of `return(x)` (which is wrapped in unnecessary brackets) to the object `my_func`.You are, practically, typing something like `function(x) y <- x` which cannot result in a function `y` defined as `function(x) x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for "function" in R show the following usage

```
function( arglist ) expr
```

So basically everything after `function()` will be interpreted as an expression and used as the function body. It just so happens that the assignment operator can be interpreted as part of that expression. Note that this is a valid expression in R

```
{1 - 2} -> x
```

So you are basically defining a function that does the assignment. You are not creating by evaluating that statement -- only defining an unnamed function. So for your example

```
function(x) {
    x
} -> my_func
```

This line nerver creates a variable named `my_func`. It creates a function that will assign to a variable named `my_func` but that variable will only exist in the function scope and will not be available after the function finished running.

In your actual example, you used `return` so that local variable will never actually be created because the `return()` happens in the code block before the assignment completes. But if you did a global assignment, that would be more clear

```
if (exists("my_func")) rm(my_func)
exists("my_func")
# [1] FALSE
f <- function(x) {
    x
} ->> my_func
f(5)
exists("my_func")
# [1] TRUE
```

But you can see that if you run, that variable is never created

```
if (exists("my_func")) rm(my_func)
function(x) {
    x
} -> my_func
exists("my_func")
# [1] FALSE
```

When you use `x <- function() {}` with a new line after, these is a clear break so the parser knows where the expression ends. Adding in the `()` also makes is clear to the parse where the function expression ends so R doesn't gobble the assignment into the expression (function body) as well. Functions in R don't require curly braces or explicit `return()` calls: `function(x) x` is a valid function definition.

Answer (score 4):

Without parenthesis the assignment `->` is in the body of the function. So when you do

```
function(x) {
    return(x)
} -> my_func
```

it is like

```
function(x) {
    my_func <- {return(x)}
}
```

You can see that for instance by creating a variable:

```
a <- function(x) {
        return(x)
     } -> my_func

debug(a)

a(1)
```

Then it prompts the function as understood by R:

```
> a(1)
debugging in: a(1)
debug: my_fun <- {
    return(x)
}
```